# How to set column width which uses flex

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, less

> I am working on react web app which has less styling, so under
> wrapper I have 3 columns, such that leftWrap is col-3, rightWrap is
> col-4, and rest width is centerWrap. How can i apply flex while i just
> know its col-* classnames

```
 <div className={styles.Home__wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.Home__leftWrap}> .... </div>
      <div className={styles.Home__centerWrap}> .... </div>
      <div className={styles.Home__rightWrap}> .... </div>
    </div>

.Home {
 &__wrapper {
  display : flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width : 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 &__leftWrap {
  display : flex;
 }
 &__rightWrap {
  display : flex;
 }
 &__centerWrap {
  display : flex;
 }
}
```

> How to set width to each column className as per above mentioned, is
> it through cal() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `display` CSS attribute on the container div to `flex`, and play with the `flex` attribute on the children elements. Flex will sum up the `flex` number assigned to each children element to calculate the "total" steps to be filled, then calculate the value of each step based on the available space remaining and calculate the display width of each child by multiplying the calculated step width value by the child element `flex` value. In your case, it looks like your left and right children have fixed widths, and you want the center element to take the remaining space, so just set `flex` to `1` on the center element.

```css
._wrapper {
  display : flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 ._leftWrap {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
 }
 ._rightWrap {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
 }
 ._centerWrap {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div class="_wrapper">
      <div class="_leftWrap"> .... </div>
      <div class="_centerWrap"> .... </div>
      <div class="_rightWrap"> .... </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks , this works. Can you explain why flex: 1

Comment: Children of an element with `display:flex` can use the `flex` attribute to take the remaining available horizontal space. If child1 needs `33%` and child2 `67%`, you add `#child1{flex:1}` and `#child2{flex:2}`. So the total number of "steps" would be `1+2=3`, and the available space would be divided by `3`; each step would be of around `33%`, child1 takes `33%x1=33%` and child2 `33%x2=66%`. In your case you have only 1 child, so with `flex:1`, the step size is `100%` and the child takes `100%x1=100%`. Any number works for a single child.